# Making a Powershell 3.0 script work on a node with 2.0 on it

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

Is there any kind of plugin, or translator to make Powershell 3.0 code 2.0 compliant? I have a client who refuses to upgrade from 2.0 to 3.0. All my scripts (and I've learned in 3.0) are 3.0. So if I try to copy my scripts to any node and run them I get errors (syntax).

Answer (score 1):

There is no such official tool, and I am unaware of any third party tool.

Are they really syntax errors or are they missing cmdlets? There weren't a whole lot of syntax changes from 2 to 3.

In any case, it should be easy enough to track down each one and fix it.

Note that on your own machine with v3 or v4 you can run `powershell.exe -Version 2.0` to aid in testing this out.

StackOverflow is a good place to post if you're not sure how to make a specific piece of code work in 2.0 when it runs fine on 3.0.

Comment: Agreed.  Really the biggest issues I have are how you have to make possibly single or zero element collections an explicit array if you want the array member functions (`Count()`) by wrapping them in a `@()`, the changes to `Get-ChildItem`, and, IIRC, being unable to pipe from `Where-Object` to another cmdlet.  That's easily 95% of the changes.  It's tedious, but it's not hard.  Beyond that its... changes to PSObjects?

Comment: @BaconBits I've not had a problem in v2 piping the results of `Where-Object` to another cmdlet. The array thing is true, though.

Comment: Hm, I may be thinking of a limitation of remoting or v1 or a different cmdlet.  I just remember something not working right because it didn't support complete object passthru, and it went away with v3.

Answer (score 0):

Sapien's PowerShell Studio allows you to set a target environment (v2,v3,32-bit,64-bit,STA,MTA) This won't fix your scripts for you but it will allow you to target that environment and get intellisense and help for that version of powershell. It's a bit pricey but if you are on a corporate budget, getting them to spring for it may be worth it.

Note: I am not endorsing a product, just making people aware of it's existence.